# Why do I get a SIGABRT here?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, file-handling

I have this code segment in which I am opening/closing a file a number of times (in a loop):

```
for(i=1;i<max;i++)
     {
       /* other code */
       plot_file=fopen("all_fitness.out","w");
       for (j=0;j<pop_size;j++)
         fprintf(plot_file, "%lf %lf\n",oldpop[i].xreal[0],oldpop[i].obj);
       fclose(plot_file);
      /*other code*/
     }
```

I get a SIGABRT here, with the following backtrace:

```
#0  0x001fc422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x002274d1 in *__GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#2  0x0022a932 in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:92
#3  0x0025dee5 in __libc_message (do_abort=2, fmt=0x321578 "*** glibc detected *** %s: %s: 0x%s ***\n")
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:189
#4  0x00267ff1 in malloc_printerr (action=<value optimized out>, str=0x6 <Address 0x6 out of bounds>, ptr=0x8055a60) at malloc.c:6217
#5  0x002696f2 in _int_free (av=<value optimized out>, p=<value optimized out>) at malloc.c:4750
#6  0x0026c7cd in *__GI___libc_free (mem=0x8055a60) at malloc.c:3716
#7  0x0025850a in _IO_new_fclose (fp=0x8055a60) at iofclose.c:88
#8  0x0804b9c0 in main () at ga.c:1100
```

The line number 1100, is the line where I am doing the `fclose()` in the above code segment.  What is the reason for the above behavior? Any pointers is appreciated.

(I am on Linux and using gcc)

Comment: Your are using the same i in both of your loops, is that intentional?

Comment: @IVlad: Thanks for pointing it out. It was an error in the question posting. Fixed it.

Comment: What's with the malloc_printerr message? Are you sure the fclose() is causing the crash? I think you should reduce your code to exactly the part that causes the problem and post that...

Comment: Well, as the backtrace shows, the crash was caused at line 1100, which is my fclose() line, if I remove that line, it runs fine.

Comment: What happens if you move the fopen before the first for (the one with i) and the fclose after it? The way this is now your all_fitness.out file will get overwritten at each iteration of i, which is not what you want, I'm guessing?

Comment: That's what I want: the file contents should be over-written every iteration.

Comment: Hello, I tried to complete your code snippet with some variables, but no error occurred. Can your code be more detailed??

Comment: Curious -- what's the value of  i  at the time of abort?  Is it the first, last, or somewhere in the middle (and is that consistent between runs)?

Comment: Also, are there any other threads doing anything at the same time? The "str=0x6 <Address 0x6 out of bounds>" part of the message makes me wonder if something is getting corrupted along the way.

Comment: You want `oldpop[j]` instead of `oldpop[i]` - not sure if this is a copy-paste error or a bug in your code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you call `fclose()`, glibc releases some dynamically allocated structures; internally there is a `free()` call. `malloc()` and `free()` rely on rather complex, dynamically built structures. Apparently, glibc found that the structures were in an incoherent state, to the point that safe memory release cannot be done. glibc decided that the problem was serious enough to warrant an immediate abort.

This means that you have a bug somewhere in your code, possibly quite far from the snippet you show, a buffer overflow or a similar out-of-place memory write which damages the memory allocation structures.

You may want to try [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or [Electric Fence](http://perens.com/FreeSoftware/ElectricFence/) to sort such problems out.

Comment: Hello Thomas: Yes, the bug was somewhere else. Valgrind helped me figure it out. So, thanks for your hint. After your answer, I really dug into the code, and have corrected a rather stupid, overlooked mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's causing your particular problem, but you should always check the `FILE *` pointer returned by `fopen()` in case it's `NULL`.

Comment: I have put a check, nothing fishy. Thanks :)